# How to open python software only once

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

i Have developed python application with `tkinter` framework which is working well on windows platform but the challenge am having is that i can open this application several times as it is shown in the image attached.

I want the application to open only once. If the app is opened and the user clicks on the icon on the desktop to open it again it shouldn't open because it is already being opened.

I want to achieve this function as it works in apps like `Teamviewer` , `pycharm` and etc.

Your suggestions are welcome to achieve this.

**EDIT**

This the how am trying to `terminate` the but after adding this to the code the executable doesn't runned again;

```
import psutil
import tkinter as tk




root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("400x400")



b = tk.Button(root, text="hello world button", command=None)
b.place(x=200, y=100)



PROCNAME = "myapp.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        # check whether the process name matches
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
            print("Running, exit(1).")
            exit(1)

else:
    print("not running, continue to startup.")
    root.mainloop()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Find [running processes using psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes) and terminate.

Comment: What code do you currently have to try to implement this?

Comment: @stovfl: why terminate? I think the OP wants to prevent multiple processes, not detect them and terminate them.

Comment: @BryanOakley: *"why terminate?"*: On startup, if find a running process of the app, the second started app have to terminate.

Comment: @stovfl or you know, block the processes from starting.

Comment: @stovfl not a place to continue comment chains so last one from me. Roughly speaking when clicking on an executable, you could check if a process already exists, if so don't start the new process, maybe bring the current one into focus? I don't know if Tkinter has something built in for this function, hence I didn't answer.

Comment: @stovfl see how trying do it but am not able to get the desired result it terminate app after running it.

Comment: @stovfl   how can get the second instance of the app to terminate that one

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: How to open python software only once

My Comment,
*Find running processes using psutil and terminate.*
**should be written**
*Find running processes using psutil and **exit**.*

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    PROCNAME = "myapp.exe"

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        # check whether the process name matches
        if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
            print("Running, exit(1).")
            exit(1)

    print("not running, continue to startup.")
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: am finding hard to implement because i wrote the app using `functions` not `class`

Comment: Move the code block `for proc ... exit(1)` to the top of your code, only `import psutil` before are needed.

Comment: @OJOE: Please, response as comment in my GitHub Issues comments.

Comment: @OJOE You have lost the link, click on [Issues](https://github.com/wan-joe/OPEN-TKINTER-APP-ONCE/issues) to see mey response.

Comment: have responded to the project.